# Xcode auto-completion - replace text keystroke?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

Say we have a TestClass with the 2 methods, `-getSomeString` and `-getAnotherString`, and we are editing the following code and the cursor is in the location shown:

```
NSString *aString = [TestClass get<cursorIsHere>SomeString];
```

Say I want to change it to use `-getAnotherString`. If I bring up the auto-completion popup and select the other method via hitting enter or tab, I'm left with:

```
NSString *aString = [TestClass getAnotherStringSomeString];
```

i.e., it doesn't replace the existing text but rather just inserts.

Is there a special keystroke to make it replace the remaining text?

See IntelliJ for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is a one step operation to achieve this. My suggestion would be similar to Thomas Templemann, but rather than two steps of forward word select and then Delete, I would expand to the desired autocomplete, by bouncing on **Control + .** and then hit **Option + forward delete**, which kills to the end of the word.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I have always used the following

- double click on getSomeString
- press Escape (or your autocomplete key)
- find replacement method

that double click step has never really bothered me, but I would be interested if anyone knows better!

Answer (score 0):

My work-around for this problem is this: Since the cursor will be right after the inserted text, I just press Shift-Option-Rightcursor, which selects the word past the cursor, then I hit the Delete key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Tab key to perform "replace" instead of "insert" when choosing the method from the auto-complete popup in IntelliJ 9 (don't know if it's available in previous versions).

Comment: Yes, IntelliJ is fantastic - I've been using it for 6 years now. However, the question is whether you can do this autocomplete replacing in XCode.

Comment: Oops, looks like I got confused by the "See IntelliJ for reference" line in the question body (and didn't pay enough attention to the header/title). My apologies.